# Fix for "send disconnect" error when pushing to bitbucket repo via SSH

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I have a local repository that was not pushed to bitbucket before.

My working folder (with the local .git folder) has grown to **1.7 GB**, so I decided to push it to bitbucket, as an additional backup.

1. I created a new bitbucket repo (workspace/repository.git)
2. In my local repo, I added a new SSH remote called "origin" (git@bitbucket.org:workspace/repository.git)
3. Note, that the id_rsa key is already set up locally and in bitbucket (for other projects)
4. Now, I try a `git push` but that always fails with the following error:

Output:

```
> git push

Pushing to git@bitbucket.org:workspace/repository.git
Enumerating objects: 62975, done.
Counting objects:   0% (1/62975)
Counting objects:   1% (630/62975)
...
Counting objects:  99% (62346/62975)
Counting objects: 100% (62975/62975)
Counting objects: 100% (62975/62975), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects:   0% (1/33144)
Compressing objects:   1% (332/33144)
...
Compressing objects:  99% (32813/33144)
Compressing objects: 100% (33144/33144)
Compressing objects: 100% (33144/33144), done.
Writing objects:   0% (1/62975)
Writing objects:   1% (632/62975)
Writing objects:   1% (1094/62975), 3.45 MiB | 2.79 MiB/s
...
Writing objects:  29% (18265/62975), 70.41 MiB | 1.13 MiB/s
Writing objects:  29% (18282/62975), 71.57 MiB | 1.16 MiB/s
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Based on similar issues, I have already tried to update `~/.ssh/config` to this:

```
> cat ~/.ssh/config

Host *
   ServerAliveInterval 600
   TCPKeepAlive yes
   IPQoS=throughput
```

The error happens after 30-60 seconds - it always fails at a different position.

What can cause that problem, and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is related to the SSH key, which does authenticate you correctly to BitBucket.

This is more linked to a [BitBucket repository size limit](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/reduce-repository-size/), as [listed here](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/what-kind-of-limits-do-you-have-on-repositoryfile-size/): if you have a big giant commit which is more than 1GB, that would fail to upload.

Try and use on your local repository a tool like [`github/git-sizer`](https://github.com/github/git-sizer) to evaluate not just the global size of the repository, by also the size of its largest objects.

Comment: Absolutely! After creating a new local repository I could push the changes (without the commit history of the past 2 years). Unfortunately, I could not keep the historic commits, but that's okay in my case